# Interactive SSH session for provisioning

Tags: packer

Is there anyway to open an interactive SSH connection after provisioner phase, but before the cleanup? Something similar to how a debugger works in scripting languages. This is useful to debug my provisioning script, especially when writing from scratch.

Simple `bash -i` doesn’t work in provisioner script, probably because no TTY is attached.

I’m using VirtualBox builder.

Answer (score 0):

My current workaround is to keep the machine running, then manually SSH into the virtual machine.  Username and password remains the same. Local SSH port can be found in VirtualBox settings; it keeps changing, but `host_port_min` and `host_port_max` can be abused here if parallel isn’t required.

There are two ways to keep it running.

1. Append `sleep 1800` to provisioner script.
2. Add `--on-error=abort` to `packer build`, and returns error in provisioner script. This way Packer exits early and skips cleanup.

Notes:

1. For Packer the SSH password is typically simple and static. In that case `sshpass` is useful.
2. SSH Host key changes every time. Use `-o NoHostAuthenticationForLocalhost=yes` for that.